# Accessing template data after rendering have completed

Tags: jquery, templates, jquery-templates

I'm using jquery templates to populate a table.

I'm wondering if it's possible to access the data used to populate the table after the rendering is complete? (I want to access it when the user have selected something in a `select`).

Or do I have to manually store that data during rendering? (i.e. store it on the `tr` using `jquery.data()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tmplItem functionality of the jQuery Templates plugin will help you do this: http://api.jquery.com/tmplitem/

you can do something like:

```
var myTmplItem = $("#target").tmplItem();
```

Then access it like:

```
myTmplItem.data
```

data will be set to whatever the context was of the entire template that was being rendered.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/tLnwx/

I would also put a plug in for [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com), it allows this type of connection between elements and your underlying data to happen automatically via declarative bindings added to your elements.  It supports jQuery Templates as a template engine.